# WebLogic Class Not Found Exception

Tags: weblogic12c

I am facing an issue deploying a web application into WebLogic server 12c. Web application has a dependency on a service jar ( which internally has a dependency on hibernate classes). When I am building the war its not including the hibernate-entitymanager.jar in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder of web application and its deployment is failing with exception **"ClassNotFoundException org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"**.

I can add missing hibernate jar details into web application pom. But if i doing I am ending up adding all of the hibernate related jars into web application which is not recommended.

Is there any other way that i can make those jars available to the application when it runs ?

Comment: You may create and link custom shared libraries https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#WLPRG325

Comment: thanks for the reply, not sure whether is right approach or not but i solved it by adding entity manager dependency in pom xml and then updated the package in weblogic.xml in section prefer-application tag.

Answer (score 0):

All

I resolved it by adding dependency to the pom ie hibernate-entitymanager and then updated weblogic.xml with below details

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.hibernate</wls:package-name>
 </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: Right, this is another approach, the only difference is where the jar files are stored.